# version code not changing of APK or Android App Bundle in the flutter. Even after changing it from pubspec.yaml

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-services, flutter-dependencies, flutter-release

### Version Code not changing

In my **appBundle** version code is not changing even after changing the code in `pubspec.yaml`

```
version: 1.0.0+4
```

But its showing the same error while uploading the app in the *google playstore*.

[image: Playstore Error]

What to do now. I can change the version code from the android file in the `build.gradle`->.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    ....
    versionCode 4
    versionName flutterVersionName
    ....
}
```

But I want to change it from the `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: Try flutter clean command, before you build appbundle.

Comment: @DIVYANSHUSAHU, on android module ***android>local.properties*** update the version code and name too will fix the problem

Comment: @ॐRakeshKumar i have written that in my question that I know that method.

Comment: @DIVYANSHUSAHU, where have you written?(In your question)

Comment: ***android>local.properties*** means change the version code in `local.properties` Right.    But I have already done changes in the `defaultConfig` where it takes versioncode from the *local.properties*.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `--build-name=1.0.0 --build-number=1` when you're building your apk.

For example: `flutter build apk --split-per-abi --build-name=1.0.0 --build-number=1`

Comment: Still not working. It still builds the previous version only.